# Why jasmine test fails for Angular Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap

I'm very new to Angular so this could be a stupid question but I couldn't find how to solve my problem on stackoverflow (maybe because of my knowledge level), so let me post this question and I would very much appreciate if someone can help me solve it.

I'm using Angular Bootstrap Modal (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) but keep having an error message for ONLY test;

> Error: No component factory found for notifyModalContent. Did you add it to `@NgModule.entryComponents`?.

(Dialog pops up with ng serve without problem)

I checked `app.module.ts` contains `declarations: myModalContent`, `imports: NgbModule(or NgbModule.forRoot())`, `entryComponents: [notifyModalContent]`.
Also I added `{ provide: NgbActiveModal, useClass: NgbActiveModal }` in overrideComponent in `product.component.spec.ts` but still doesn't work.

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { myModalContent } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProductComponent,
    myModalContent,
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [myModalContent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

product.component.spec.ts

```js
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import { myModalContent } from '../my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


describe('ProductComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductComponent, myModalContent ],
    })
        .overrideComponent(ProductComponent, {
          set: {
            providers: [
              { provide: DataService, useClass: MockDataService },
              { provide: NgbActiveModal, useClass: NgbActiveModal }
            ]
          }
        })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

product.component.ts

```js
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { myModalContent } from "../my-dialog/my-dialog.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-product",
  templateUrl: "./product.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./product.component.scss"]
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

    errorDialog() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyModalContent, {
      centered: true
    });
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = "Open dialog";
  }

}
```

I removed some of general parts such as async, ComponentFicture, dataservice import etc.

Answer (score 9):

This is the way I tend to set out my modal tests. Hope it helps.

```
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import { myModalContent } from '../my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

describe('ProductComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;    

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ProductComponent,
        myModalContent
      ],
      imports: [
        NgbModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DataService, useClass: MockDataService },
        NgbActiveModal,
        NgbModal
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

});
```

Comment: If you could provide your product.component.ts it would helpful to diagnose the problem

Comment: I have added `product.component.ts`. It is actually long code so I provided only modal part. I hope it is enough, thank you!